# How to display the saved content of a DraftJS editor?

Tags: javascript, draftjs

I am actually saving the `contentState` of my DraftJS editor as a string, using: `JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))`

My question is: How to display it back, as a Post for example. I am thinking that I should still use DraftJS to display it back, since only DraftJS can naturally parse the result of `convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(...))`.

The problem is that the Link entities for example are not clickable in the editor, and when I browse the API of `EditorState` and `ContentState`, I don't see something like `viewMode`, or something like that, so I am confuse.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the rawContent by doing something like this:

```
import { Editor} from 'draft-js';

export default class ShowContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.state = { editorState: convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(...))};
  }

  render(){
    return <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} readOnly />
  }
}
```

Your assumption about a `viewMode` property is correct. It's the "readOnly" attribute on the Editor component you import from Draft.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Mike.

Comment: For anyone arriving here in the future: Apart from the `readOnly` prop, there's also a `blockStyleFn` (function) prop which can be used for styling the blocks. Based on the content type being rendered, you can `return` the appropriated className to style it (typical use case: text-alignment).
Reference: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor/#blockstylefn

Answer (score 0):

I just saw [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html), just what I was looking for.